# How to parse "temp" from Json in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I need to get "temp", name and description out of this JSON format. I can get some of these out but not all, I went through the questions but I could not get a specific answer.

```
HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=XXX"));

WebReq.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

string jsonString;
//modified from your code since the using statement disposes the stream 
//automatically when done
using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())   
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsonString);

foreach (var item in obj)
{
}
```

JSON FORMAT:

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":-0.13,
      "lat":51.51
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":300,
         "main":"Drizzle",
         "description":"light intensity drizzle",
         "icon":"09d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":280.32,
      "pressure":1012,
      "humidity":81,
      "temp_min":279.15,
      "temp_max":281.15
   },
   "visibility":10000,
   "wind":{
      "speed":4.1,
      "deg":80
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":90
   },
   "dt":1485789600,
   "sys":{
      "type":1,
      "id":5091,
      "message":0.0103,
      "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1485762037,
      "sunset":1485794875
   },
   "id":2643743,
   "name":"London",
   "cod":200
}
```

Comment: I hope you change your app id... someone can use it and abuse it. Never post these things.

Comment: Its a sample @Çöđěxěŕ not mine but thank you

Comment: https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22 @EdPlunkett, cant post it here too long

Comment: @mohamad please remove `json` comment, I already updated your post.

Comment: Sorry btw for the mess, I am just new to this.

Comment: @mohamad it's fine. If you take that `json` and head over to [here](http://json2csharp.com/) post it all and it will tell you what your objects should be... Do you have any classes that would represent this response?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to use `Json.NET` (NuGet). Then, create a model for the json, you can use some online tools like [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io) and [Json Editor Online](http://jsoneditoronline.org/) to help you converting Json to Object. Then, use the model with the `Json.NET` to Deserialize it (in other word, mapping the Json to the Model).

Then, use the new created object to access the json values.

Here is an example of your Json (Using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)):

Model :

```
public class WeatherCast
{
    [JsonProperty("coord")]
    public Coord Coord { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weather")]
    public Weather[] Weather { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("base")]
    public string Base { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public Main Main { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("visibility")]
    public long Visibility { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("wind")]
    public Wind Wind { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("clouds")]
    public Clouds Clouds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dt")]
    public long Dt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sys")]
    public Sys Sys { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cod")]
    public long Cod { get; set; }



}

public class Weather
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public string Main { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

}
public class Clouds
{
    [JsonProperty("all")]
    public long All { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    [JsonProperty("lon")]
    public double Lon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public double Lat { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    [JsonProperty("temp")]
    public double Temp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pressure")]
    public long Pressure { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("humidity")]
    public long Humidity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temp_min")]
    public double TempMin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temp_max")]
    public double TempMax { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public long Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public double Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sunrise")]
    public long Sunrise { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sunset")]
    public long Sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    [JsonProperty("speed")]
    public double Speed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deg")]
    public long Deg { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using Json.NET you do this :

```
var json = "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-0.13,\"lat\":51.51},\"weather\":[{\"id\":300,\"main\":\"Drizzle\",\"description\":\"light intensity drizzle\",\"icon\":\"09d\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":280.32,\"pressure\":1012,\"humidity\":81,\"temp_min\":279.15,\"temp_max\":281.15},\"visibility\":10000,\"wind\":{\"speed\":4.1,\"deg\":80},\"clouds\":{\"all\":90},\"dt\":1485789600,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":5091,\"message\":0.0103,\"country\":\"GB\",\"sunrise\":1485762037,\"sunset\":1485794875},\"id\":2643743,\"name\":\"London\",\"cod\":200}";

var forecast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherCast>(json);

var temp = forecast.Main.Temp;
var name = forecast.Name;
var description = forecast.Weather[0].Description;
```